# Why Matlab engine does not work on python3.7 via pycharm?

Tags: python, matlab, python-import, matlab-engine, system-integration

I install matlab.engine on python3.7 (Ubuntu) as explained in the matlab site:

```
cd "matlabroot/extern/engines/python"
python setup.py install
```

But when I try to use in Pycharm as:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.start_matlab()
tf = eng.isprime(37)
print(tf)
```

Come the error "No module named 'matlab.engine'; 'matlab' is not a package"
I have a lot of matlab function that are not so easy to translate to python. If I could just open then in python3.7 via Pycharm could be much mode easy.

Comment: did it install correctly? is it in your site-packages? are you using environmentS?

Comment: I don't know. It does not give any error in the terminal installation, it was very straightforward. But it does not run in Pycharm and I already install matlab_kernel.

Comment: find your site packages folder and see if there is a matlab package there

Comment: Yes. There is a file matlab.py

Comment: cd to that folder in python and try to import matlab..if it works, then either your sitepackages folder is not in your path or you installe the package into the wrong environment

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your version of MATLAB supports python 3.7.

Here is a [link](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/python-support.pdf) to a list for which python version is supported by which MATLAB version.

According to the document, for you to run the matlab engine in python 3.7 your version of MATLAB must be R2019a or higher

Comment: Thanks. I find also Oc2py. Works well, bot it is very slow. Do you know if matlab.engine is very slow too?

Comment: That would depend on the way you use the matlab engine. I did not see your code but I'm guessing you might be fequently starting a new session. Starting a session (calling `matlab.engine.start_matlab()`) takes relatively a long time.

@EdilsonFerreira